# Derivation of Equation 10.97 in Zettili: Quantization of the EM Field

Tags: electromagnetism, perturbation-theory, quantization

I am reading through Zettili, and I am stuck on one of the steps that Zetilli makes when quantizing the EM field, specifically with page 567.

Zettili first introduces the Fourier series for the potential vector, as such:

$$\vec{A}(\vec{r},t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_\vec{k}\sum_{\lambda=1}^2\left[A_{\lambda,
\vec{k}}\vec{\varepsilon}_\lambda e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega_kt)}+A_{\lambda,
\vec{k}}^*\vec{\varepsilon}^*_\lambda e^{-i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega_kt)}\right]$$

I can follow and understand how he got this equation, and it makes sense to me. He then goes to determine the Hamiltonian of the EM field, stating the following step:

$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{8\pi}\int~dr^3\left(\vec{E}^2(\vec{r},t)+\vec{B}^2(\vec{r},t)\right) = \frac{1}{8\pi c^2}\sum_{\vec{k}}\sum_{\lambda=1}^2(\hbar \vec{k}^2)A^*_{\lambda,\vec{k}}A_{\lambda,\vec{k}}$$

To go from the middle part of the equation to the right hand side feels quite the leap. He provides a few hints, saying that they used the fact that $\vert\vec{\varepsilon}_\lambda\vert^2=1$, $\omega_k=ck$, $\vec{E}=-(1/c)\partial \vec{A}/\partial t$, and $\vec{B}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}$. However, I don't see how he did it.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how he did this. It is very possible that he didn't do anything too crazy and I'm just over thinking it. With that said, any guiding thoughts will prove to be useful!

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I was foolish to think that such a leap was simple, lol. I thought maybe there was some identity I wasn’t aware of. I’ll plan on using tomorrow to work on that

Comment: I started to, but I figured there would be an easier move between the two that I just forgot or didn’t know of, and I figured the squaring process would be quite length, as you suggest. If I have more questions tomorrow, I’ll be sure to come back

Comment: Huh, I think whoever commented originally deleted their comment, and they gave some pretty useful advice, so if someone sees this in the future, that’s why I seem like I’m talking to myself, lol

Comment: My next question may answer it for me, can I simply use Parseval’s theorem for this?